# Django 1.11.9 and PosgreSQL10 on Docker makes duplicated tables

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

Today I got a weird behaviour. I am not sure this problem comes from AWS EC2 or Django itself. Today AWS shows me significant lack and poor performance.

I use `PostgreSQL10` on `Docker`

And what should I do with replicated tables?
I can not `Drop` it. I had tried.

[image]

Comment: what's the error msg?

Comment: try to rename and delete the renamed table

Comment: @renqHIT Thank you for your comments. It is a good idea to rename it. By that I did backed up first and when I restored it back to my local database instance duplications are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @renqHIT. During the way to rename it I backed/restore on my local computer and they are gone!

Comment: how about transfer my comment into an answer and accept it?  :)

Comment: @renqHIT Seems like it was db client bug, how you mind to make the tables with the same name?

Comment: @Denis Good point! I was updating the JDBC driver during the time. But on different connection. Next time when I upgrade I will be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

**Rename and delete the renamed table usually can solve this problem.**

How do you make these tables, by Django's `syncdb` command?
I suppose it's a Django usage problem.

Two table with same name may come from different namespace, one is permanent table and the other is temperate table.
[See this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69776/23420)

Comment: I use migration on Postgres.